# ANdroid Studio dont let me create Layout-small res folder

Tags: android, android-layout

I already made the layout.xml in the layout folder, but for a small device its not working

[image]

than = then =x

and after reading some articles, i must create a layout-small isnt it?

so im trying to do in android studio, it dont allow me saying that it already exist, BUT there is not layout-small folder =/ i should i do?

[image]

**EDIT***

i already tried to create a folder manually in windows and restart android studio, not working too...

what i saw is that while gradle is building, i show all the folders, but after gradle finishes, it HIDE the folder

Look:

WHILE BUILDING:

[image]

AFTER BUILDING:

[image]

Comment: It has already said "File already exists", isn't it clear? Open `layout`, you will see layout files in `small` if you have created files in there.

Comment: why say isnt it clear? i already said in the question that It doesnt appaer, even in the windows explorer, but when i try to create again, it says "Already Exist", isnt it clear?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is wrong with your AS. Maybe it's a bug, or just this happens in your AS.

Comment: no problem, i solved(not the error of the fodler hide) but i went to the Design and selected to create ldpi design and it worked =)

thx anyway

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little bit stupid, but did you try creating this folder manually using Windows? If it is already, maybe restart Android Studio?

Also [Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2 and greater, see Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2 for more information.